# connect to mysql , CSHTML

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, razor, database-connection

I have the following code:

```
  @{

    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "About";
    if(Request["id"].IsEmpty()){
    Write("something");
} else {
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   var Id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();  
    var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery");
    var selectQueryString = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Products where Id={0}", Id);  
}


}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
          <table>  

            <tr>  

                <th>Product</th>  

            </tr>  
      @if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >0){

            <tr>  
                <td>@row.Id</td>  
                <td>@row.Name</td>


            </tr>  

          }
    </table>  
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem here that I get an error in this line :"@if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)"

My question is why and how can I fix it (I just start learn this and it is new for me...)
Thanks.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Two problems that pop out are that you are clearly not referencing any assembly that works with databases, and that you renamed 'db' to 'ds' (probably) in that if line. Can you please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve and how would you plan to do it?

Comment: Hi, thnks for your anser. I'm trying to see only the values in the tables where the id is the id int the Url (http://example.com/ViewDish.cshtml?id=1)
I want to get this ID and select all the values from the table in this Id, but i'm getting this error "CS0103: The name 'ds' does not exist in the current context" Why??

Answer (score 0):

For one, I don't see `ds` declared and set anywhere, so are you sure it exists? Are you sure you assign to it? Also there's potential for a `NullReferenceException` here even if `ds` is a `DataSet` and has been assigned to, since there's no checking to see if there is at least one table before you try to access one at the first index.

So, to be thorough in this respect (and any scenario-specific logic you're free to add), you could do:

```
@if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) {
```

Comment: Hi, thnks for your anser , but it didn't works.... I'm trying to see only the values in the tables where the id is the id int the Url (example.com/ViewDish.cshtml?id=1) I want to get this ID and select all the values from the table in this Id, but i'm getting this error "CS0103: The name 'ds' does not exist in the current context" Why??

Comment: Then, as I first stated, to that script, ds does not exist as a thing. Indeed, there is nothing named ds in your posted script, you only open the db and don't execute anything against it to get the resulting dataset.

Comment: Only now I see you have added the dataset variable `ds` to your code. It wasn't there before, and you're still not making anything useful out of it (just an empty dataset within which there is no tables).

Comment: Thanks. So can you pleas tell me what should I do? (I just started learn this)...

Comment: You need to execute a query against your open `db` and assign the result to `ds`

Answer (score 0):

ds is not always declared and never initialised. See your initial statements:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "About";
    if(Request["id"].IsEmpty()) {
       Write("something");
    } else {
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       var Id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();  
       var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery");
       var selectQueryString = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Products where Id={0}", Id);  
   }
```

}

First, if there isn't an id in the query string, ds isn't declared at all. That will be one error.
Then, if there is an id, ds is declared as a new dataset but not given a value (other than an empty dataset). That's another possible error.

You could structure it this way:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "About";
    if(Request["id"].IsEmpty()) {
       Write("something");
    } else {
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       var Id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();  
       var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery");
       var selectQueryString = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Products where Id={0}", Id); 
       ds = ... **** Use the query here to fill the ds with the required data ****

       **** put the HTML here - this HTML code is not needed
            in the other branch of the if statement ****
   }
```

}

Comment: THank you, but I get this error "The type or namespace name 'DataSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference" why?

Comment: Because you are using data of type "DataSet", and that type is not available unless you tell your system that you need it. @Nave, we can only help you so far. You have to do it to learn, but also we don't know everything about your system. Everyone of your comments is about a different error... If there is a string of errors in your work, you can't just report them here and hope that we can solve them all from half your code and no access to your platform. You have to use our answers as a starting point to reason about what your system is doing, read them alongside other sources, and find out.